# How can you explain this code? Coursera lambda python

Tags: python, lambda

i'm taking a course in Coursera but i did't undestand very good how lambda works... if anyone can tell my about this example i will apreciate it, thank

```
people = ['Dr. Christopher Brooks', 'Dr. Kevyn Collins-Thompson', 'Dr. VG Vinod Vydiswaran', 'Dr. Daniel Romero']


def split_title_and_name(person):
    return person.split()[0] + ' ' + person.split()[-1]

#option 1
for person in people:
    print(split_title_and_name(person) == (lambda x: x.split()[0] + ' ' + x.split()[-1])(person))

#option 2
list(map(split_title_and_name, people)) == list(map(lambda person: person.split()[0] + ' ' + person.split()[-1], people))
```

Comment: ??? what do you need help with

Comment: I don't undestand very good how it works... i mean in the #option1 i think the x is equal to the "person" variable into people, am i right? It works but i don't understand pretty good the how... thank u

Comment: could you tell us what the question is in the first place, we dont even know if the code works without seeing the requirements

Comment: The code works, its a solution gived by coursera but i don't understand pretty well how the lambda function works in this case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean to focus on

```
(lambda x: x.split()[0] + ' ' + x.split()[-1])(person)
```

so let's break it down...

**first... the contents of the function**

1. `x.split()[0]` | splits the string by spaces and gets the `0`th index of the returned list | e.g if `x` was "iron key" this would return `"iron"`
2. `x.split()[-1]` | similar to the last but this gives the last element of the list returned; presumably the *last name*

**now the lambda function its self**

1. `lambda x` | declares a function with one parameter: `x`
2. `(lamda x: ...)(person)` | calls that function passing `person` as the x parameter

---

`lambda person: person.split()[0] + ' ' + person.split()[-1]` is the same thing, except it just uses `person` as a parameter.

Comment: Hi, can you explain why lambda person: person.split()[0] + ' ' + person.split()[-1]   doesn't give the same result as (lambda x: x.split()[0] + ' ' + x.split()[-1])(person)?